# validate that I have received an email at gmail server

Tags: gmail

I have received an email from Mr. A. That email is at a gmail server.  But Mr. A. disputes that I have made up this email. Is there any way to validate this email?

Answer (score 2):

You can get evidence, but probably not proof.

The key is going to be to look at the headers of the email you received, and how you do that varies depending on your email software. If you're also a gmail user then you can follow the steps below. If not, there's a [gmail help page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22454?hl=en) that will hopefully provide some direction.

- Log in to Gmail
- Open the message you'd like to view headers for.
- Click the down arrow next to Reply, at the top of the message pane.
- Select Show Original.
- The full headers will appear in a new window.

The email headers indicate the path the message took as it crossed servers on its way between the sender and the recipient. They're in reverse chronological order, so the arrival of the message at your mailserver will be at the top, and the sending of the message will be one or more steps below that.

Since gmail requires users to supply their username and password for messages to be sent, and doesn't allow you to pretend to be someone you're not, if the message did indeed come from a gmail server then you can be reasonably confident that it was sent by the account it says it's from.